# Ajax callback to originating page from different controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am using Ajax to post data to a different controller for an application I am building. A user gets points for answering questions correctly.

My originating view is: **app/views/questions/index.html.erb**

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/points/create" method="post" data-remote="true" id="formname"> 
                <div class="field">
                    <%= radio_button("point", :user_answer, 1) %>
                    <%= label_tag(:correct_answer, question.answer1 ) %>
                    <%= radio_button("point", :user_answer, 2) %>
                    <%= label_tag(:correct_answer, question.answer2) %>
                    <%= radio_button("point", :user_answer, 3) %>
                    <%= label_tag(:correct_answer, question.answer3) %>
                    <%= radio_button("point", :user_answer, 4) %>
                    <%= label_tag(:correct_answer, question.answer4) %>
                  </div>
                <div class="actions">
                    <input type="hidden" id="point_question_correct_answer" name="point[correct_answer]" value="<%= question.correct_answer %>" />
                    <input type="hidden" id="point_question_id" name="point[question_id]" value="<%= question.id %>" />
                    <input type="hidden" id="point_current_user" name="point[user_id]" value="<%= current_user.id %>" />

                   <%= submit_tag "Submit", :class => 'btn btn-primary' %> 
                </div>
```

I am able to post and save data in: **app/controllers/points_controller.rb**:

```
 def create
@point = Point.new(params[:point])

respond_to do |format|
  if @point.save
    logger.debug "Data has been saved"
    flash[:success] = "Data has been saved" 
  else
      end
    end
  end
```

The problem is that I want the flash[:success] to appear in the current view (**..questions/index.html.erb**). The message flashes on view/points, which is not the current view.  The `flash[:success]` should appear on **view/questions/index.html.erb**. 
Is there something I'm doing wrong or not including?

Comment: Any particular reason you aren't using form builder?
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for

Comment: @Jeff - started really learning rails a week or so ago, so I'm still getting used to the form builders.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. Did flash.now do it for you?

Also, Rails Guides are great: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#binding-a-form-to-an-object

Comment: For sure...Everything else was going smoothly, I think there's something fundamental I'm not getting with this because it should be quite simple yet I'm banging my head against the wall..

Answer (score 0):

`flash[:success]` expects a redirect aftwards.

Try `flash.now[:success] = "Data has been saved"` instead.
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#flash-now

Comment: tried flash.now, to no avail....think I might explore doing this in a non-Ajaxian way if I can't figure it out.